# How to insert data from OpenSearch to Excel using python

Tags: python, opensearch

I have already written code but still having some trouble with below two scenarios.

1. Inserting More than 10k records
2. Setting up incremental load

Reference: opensearch-py can be used as a python client

Sample Code:

```
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch

host = ''
port = 
auth = ('', '') 

# Create the client with SSL/TLS enabled, but hostname verification disabled.
client = OpenSearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': port}],
    http_compress = True, # enables gzip compression for request bodies
    http_auth = auth,
    # client_cert = client_cert_path,
    # client_key = client_key_path,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = False,
    ssl_assert_hostname = False,
    ssl_show_warn = False
)

# # Create an index with non-default settings.
index_name = ''

# Search for the document.
query = {
  "query": {
    "match_all" : {}
  }
}

res = client.search(
    body = query,
    index = index_name,
    scroll = '2m',
    size = 10000,
)
# print('\nSearch results:')
# print(response)

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(res['hits']['hits'])
df.to_excel (r'export_dataframe.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using **scan**!

```
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch
from opensearchpy.helpers import scan

host = ''
port = 
auth = ('', '') 

# Create the client with SSL/TLS enabled, but hostname verification disabled.
client = OpenSearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': port}],
    http_compress = True, # enables gzip compression for request bodies
    http_auth = auth,
    # client_cert = client_cert_path,
    # client_key = client_key_path,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = False,
    ssl_assert_hostname = False,
    ssl_show_warn = False
)

# # Create an index with non-default settings.
index_name = ''

# Search for the document.
query = {
  "query": {
    "match_all" : {}
  }
}

res = scan(
        client=os,
        query=query,
        scroll='2s',
        index='index-name',
        raise_on_error=True,
        preserve_order=False,
        clear_scroll=True
    )
# print('\nSearch results:')
# print(response)

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(res['hits']['hits'])
df.to_excel (r'export_dataframe.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```